# jquery only execute element bound code

Tags: jquery

I don't really know how to explain my problem (or what a proper title could be) so I made a jqFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ky5Pp/2/

is there a way to make it only execute the '.tdClass' code? Now it executes the tdClass code first and then the trClass code.

so it should execute only

```
alert("cell clicked");
```

sorry for explaining my problem so poorly but I think the jsfiddle should help.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

in your `td` click event.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ky5Pp/3/)**</kbd>

```
$(".tdClass").on("click", function (e) {
        alert("cell clicked");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: alright thank you very much! can you explain short what exactly that does so I don't run into other problems using it?

Comment: It Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event..
It just avoid event bubling. In the browser whenever you have some nested elements and you have events on both of those. If you click on child element then it will fire Child click first, and then parent click and so on. to avoid that jQuery have provided this feature. Please have a look to documentation here to get a better idea.  [e.StopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: alright thank you so much! this was exactly what I was looking for! (I have to wait a couple of minutes before I can accept your answer ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Use the below:

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ky5Pp/5/)

```
$(".tdClass").on("click", function (e) { //<-pass it here
    e.stopPropagation();  // <--------------and you should stop event bubbling
    alert("cell clicked");
});
```

#### From the docs:

(*Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*)